# is this NCRONTAB expressions correct?

Tags: azure-functions

I want to create an azure function that will be called every Wednesday, once a week, at `23:00:00`, from now until `June 21st, 2020`. I have tried the following expression: `0 0 23 * * Wednesday`.
but I don't know how to stop it after `June 21st, 2020`. how can it be done?

Comment: Hi, If my solution helps you, can you mark it as the answer of the question?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use below cron expressions to do it:

`0 0 23 * Jan-May Wednesday` and `0 0 23 1-21 June Wednesday`.

That means if you want to do that, you need to use two functions.

(There are many similar problems. Don't limit your thinking to only a CRON expression. In many situation, you need to use two.:))

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try with this cron expression:

```
0 0 23 * Jan-May Wednesday
```

and another timer trigger cron expression should be:

```
0 0 23 1-21 June Wednesday
```

By the way, as cron expression in azure function can't set the year property, so if use this cron expression, you'd better to stop this function after Jan 21st. If you forget to stop it after Jan 21st, it may be triggered again in this period of time next year.